# MSI boot on power on

Tags: boot, power-management, shutdown, msi

This is really about what is likely a simple setting or motherboard jumper setting that I have missed.

What I want to do:
Following shut down through OS and then power off via mains I want the PC to reboot following power on.
Currently turning on the mains supply has no effect and I have to press the ACPI power button.

Please note I am not being too lazy to press a button, I wish to shut down the PC remotely and turn off power remotely (via phone app) and then use the phone app to boot it up and be available to access remotely (Teamviewer / SSH etc).

What Works EVERY TIME:
Leaving OS running but being brutal and remotely switching power off and on boots the system again and its accessible. Its obviously not recommended to force it like this, I wish to do a graceful shut down and then power up when required.

Board:
MSI Board FMZ-A75IA-E53

To clarify what I mean by power up following comments:
The PC has been shutdown normally (or through Teamviewer) and power turned off remotely via MiHome devices (similar to Hive or Google Home).
I now want to use the machine remotely so I use MiHome to provide power to the PC. At that point I also wish the BIOS to boot automatically. I have seen this on other BIOS something like 'boot on power on' but cannot find in on MSI board.

Comment: Quote "power up when required" - I think its possible only with 'boot by lan' in bios settings and sending special packet to PC. You may also have "power on after power failure" in bios.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding you need to "start or power on" the server remotely. The solution you are looking for is "Wake-on-Lan".

Here is a good solution for the problem you described, [Wake-on-LAN through Internet](https://hackernoon.com/wake-on-lan-through-the-internet-491817e2dd41)

To use it via Internet, you need a static IP from your ISP or you can use a Dynamic DNS. Both will cost you a few extra bucks. There are free Dynamic DNS solutions available but use them at your own risk!